# Flask-SqlAlchemy composite key one to many relationship Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently getting an error, I'm using sql server and trying to model a simple Parent with an array of Children:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
>   between parent/child tables on relationship Parent.children- there are no
>   foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns
>   are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a
>   'primaryjoin' expression.

my classes are set up simply as follows:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    parentId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parentVersion = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref="parent",lazy=True)


class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(512), nullable=False)

    parentId = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    parentVersion = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['parentId', 'parentVersion'], ['parent.parentId', 'parent.parentVersion']
```

I've tried fiddling with declaring the relationship and foreign key in several ways but i always get an error, what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to add a foreign key:

```
parentId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("parent.id))
```

There is a lot of [documentation material regarding this topic](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/constraints.html), if there is still anything unclear to you.

Comment: When I try to do that, it gives me an error saying that it cant find a foreign key to reference, which i think is because the parent table has a composite primary key?

Comment: I read the documentation you linked and it seems that syntax is for single column and not composite foreign keys. Isnt my foreignkeyconstraint syntax correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing adding the ForeignKeyConstraint to the table args, and you are using camel case, not snake case. And you don't need the `__tablename__` with Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Try:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    version = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref="parent", lazy=True)

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(512), nullable=False)

    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    parent_version = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['parent_id', 'parent_version'],
            ['parent.id', 'parent.version']
        ),
    )
```